# C# Tic Tac Toe Console App

Tags: c#, project

I created a simple Tic Tac Toe game in c#, which can played in 1 players mode, and in 2 player mode.

I programmed the computer to react correctly (in the computer vs. player mode), but I think that my code is much bigger than it should be since what I did is that I checked every possible combination manually, and can't seems to find how to minimize the code.

Here is the makeComputerMove() func: https://gist.github.com/2192374

Explanation of the variables:

char[,] Board: 2D array, contains the 'X' and 'O'

char shape: that's the shape I'm using to determine the priority move, first I set it to 'O' so that the computer will try to win. If it can't win, it will try to block. If there is nothing to block, it will try to set a 'O' near another 'O' on the board.

Position P: an object that contains the values Row and Col.

Thanks.

EDIT: Now I see that people are thinking I want you to rewrite my code. I just added it so you could see what I did. I'm only asking for tips (by approaching the problem in a different way).

Comment: You need to post you request for code review here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: So you are essentially asking us to rewrite your application?

Comment: What I was asking for is offering a different way of thinking than mine, not written code, because it will have no value for my learning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read about [MinMax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax) algorithms here to get the general idea.
It's basically backtracking through possible moves, and foreach possible move to all possible moves, and so in, into a certain number of moves (ai depth). This uses recursion.
Since this is TicTacToe, you can lose the "depth" and have "end" as your stop condition.